# Reducer can't see one particular action [react-redux]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

You are my last hope. I'm so frustrated right now...

I've just put all my project files to
[Github](https://github.com/elminsterrr/redux).

Here is my problem. Inside actions folder in index.js file I have two functions:

**fetchLocation()** & **fetchWeather()**

When user inputs city my app is dispatching action with fetchLocation and is getting data from Google Maps Api. Promise is changed to object by ReduxPromise Middleware and everything works fine. I can use this data to show that city on website using Google maps.

Now I have lat & lng so I use that data with **fetchWeather(lat, lng)**.
Inside actions/index.js  my   **fetchWeather()** function is working, because I see data in console.log. With new lat & lng it fetches new data from api.wunderground with weather forecast. And I can see this data inside console.log and request2 is a promise.

And here is this bug/strange behavior. **fetchWeather** never behaves like **fetchLocation** did. I never returns

```
  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request2
  };
```

reducer_weather.js is never triggered with switch case FETCH_WEATHER,
and I've never seen console.log('INSIDE!').

I'm using ReduxDevTootls and everything that my app does is updates states by location reducer so I can have multiple maps, but reducer_weather is always silent.

Could you please tell me why?

Here is my code from actions/index.js. Rest of my code you can find here:
[Github](https://github.com/elminsterrr/redux).

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_LOCATION = 'FETCH_LOCATION';
export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';
const API_KEY_GOOGLE = 'AIzaSyDNMmI2f7qIcBnKgV1dYXmi995BY_8zoJM';
const API_KEY_WUNDERGROUND = 'cd8c7ea98a37877f';

export function fetchLocation(city) {
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${city}&key=${API_KEY_GOOGLE}`
  const request = axios.get(url);
  console.log('request1: ', request);
  return {
    type: FETCH_LOCATION,
    payload: request
  };
}

export function fetchWeather(lat, lng) {
  console.log(lat, lng);

  const url = `https://api.wunderground.com/api/${API_KEY_WUNDERGROUND}/forecast10day/q/${lat},${lng}.json`;

  console.log(url);

  const request2 = axios.get(url);

  console.log('request2: ', request2);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request2
  };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must `dispatch` the action. But you are simply calling the action generator as normal function.

Replace [this](https://github.com/elminsterrr/redux/blob/master/src/containers/WeatherList.js#L15) line from your Repo

```
fetchWeather(lat, lng);
```

with

```
this.props.fetchWeather(lat, lng);
```

Since your actionCreators are binded with `dispatch` through [Redux Connect](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html).

*UPDATE:* `this` is not available for user defined functions(not default life cycle methods) of `Component` class. So use fat arrow functions of `es6` to access `this` inside your own functions.

Comment: Thanks for hint! Now I'm getting an error:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` And now I don't have any console.logs from fetchWeather().
Sorce of error is that line: this.props.fetchWeather(lat, lng);

Comment: Replace your `renderWeather` method as fat arrow function. i.e `renderWeather(data) {` ==> `renderWeather = (data) => {`

Comment: Oh! THANKS! You have just finished my suffering!